# create an app which runs only on one static IP address in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I want to create an flutter app which should run on only one static IP address. If the device has a different IP then it should get access to the internet.
Is this possible? if yes then how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.
You can check the IP address of your device using [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) library.
If the device IP address match with the IP address you want, you can continue the request otherwise you can reject the request and display any error message.
If you use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) in your app, you can add an interceptor and decide whether the request will be continued or rejected.

```
final dio = Dio();

Future<bool> isValidIP() async {
    final info = NetworkInfo();
    final validIP = "192.168.1.100";
    var wifiIP = await info.getWifiIP();
    return wifiIP == validIP;
}

dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest:(options, handler) async {
      if(await isValidIP())
        return handler.next(options); //continue
      else
        return handler.reject(DioError(requestOptions: options, type: DioErrorType.cancel)); //reject
    },
    onResponse:(response,handler) {
     return handler.next(response); // continue
    },
    onError: (DioError e, handler) {
     return  handler.next(e);//continue
    }
));
```

Comment: okay i am going to try it today .and i will update with the result